# Redirect Joomla core pages via .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, joomla

I'm having trouble redirecting Joomla's core pages via .htaccess; for instance, I need

```
/component/users/?view=login
```

to redirect to another page, but the server seems to ignore the redirect entirely.  Is there something I'm missing here? Currently, I'm trying to use:

```
Redirect /component/users/?view=login http://www.example.com/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't match against the query string in a `Redirect`, you need to use the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable and mod_rewrite. Above any other rules you may already have in the htaccess file in your document root, add:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)view=login(&|$)
RewriteRule ^component/users/$ http://www.example.com/? [L,R]
```

Comment: Okay, I think that's the right direction, but so far all it's doing is appending ?view=login to http://www.example.com/ instead of simply redirecting to example.com

Comment: @CuriouslyChris sorry, left out a `?`

Comment: Ahhh, that worked perfectly...but now my interest is piqued - what makes the rewrite work that way?  If I'm reading this correctly, $ represents view=login, and the RewriteRule line is replacing the first string with the second.  If that's the case, though, my browser should redirect to example.com/?, but instead it goes to example.com.  Why is that?

Comment: @CuriouslyChris The `?` in the rule's target creates a *blank query string*. And with rewrite rules, if I don't include a `QSA` flag when I create my own query string, the existing query string will not be appending (in this case, the existing query string is "view=login"). The `$` character in the regex patterns just means the end of the match.